# Django: Retrieve all details of all Test model instances assigned to a User model

Tags: python-3.x, django

> Following is my models.py models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Question(models.Model):      
  question= models.TextField()       
  optionA= models.CharField(max_length= 32)
  optionB= models.CharField(max_length= 32)
  optionC= models.CharField(max_length= 32)
  optionD= models.CharField(max_length= 32)
  answer= models.CharField(max_length= 6, choices= options, default= 'A')      

class Test(models.Model):
  
  name= models.CharField(max_length= 16)
  questions= models.ManyToManyField(Question)      

class TestTaker(models.Model):
  user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
  tests= models.ManyToManyField(Test)
```

> Following is my definition of home function that renders the website
> home inside views.py

```
def home(request):  
  try:
    tests= TestTaker.objects.filter(user= request.user).values('tests')   
    print(tests.values)     
    # tests= Test.objects.filter(user= request.user)
    return render(request, 'tests/home.html', {'tests': tests})
  except:
    print('excepted')
    return render(request, 'tests/home.html')
```

I want to extract the whole tests that are assigned to a logged in user. I can get only the test objects assigned to an authenticated user, but I want to be able to retrieve the whole of each test, along with it's questions. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to pass anything to template, you can directly render tests like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% for test in user.testtaker.tests.all %}
        {{ test }}
        {% for qus in test.questions.all %}
            {{ qus }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    Please log in
{% endif %}
```

You can directly access `TestTaker` instance of a user because it has a [`OneToOne`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) relation with `User` instance.